# Get dropped area ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page divided into two columns listing one left side and tree structure on right side. Now, I want to drop list items onto specific tree node, which I am able to do. But I am able to get only list item id and not the ID of node where item is drooped.

List Items has class 'ttlTipBU'

```
 $(".ttlTipBU").draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            refreshPositions: true,
            drag: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
                var contactID = $(this).find('div').html();
                console.log('this is contact ID----'+  contactID);

            }
        });
```

And for the tree structure node we have class implemented on each of the nodes is " orgNodeMap ", but when I drop it on node it does not perform the below action

```
$("div.orgNodeMap").on("drop", function (event, ui) {
            console.log('not coming here');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check when the the item is received, not when the item is dropped using sortable.

```js
$(".ttlTipBU").sortable({
  revert: "invalid",
  refreshPositions: true,
  connectWith: ".ttlTipBU",
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
  },
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    console.log('this is contact ID---- ' + this.id);
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
.ttlTipBU {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 2.5em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.ttlTipBU li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<ul id="sortable1" class="ttlTipBU">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="ttlTipBU">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```